# Let $\tau$ and $\nu$ be stopping times. Show that $F_{\tau \land \nu}=F_{\tau} \cap F_{\nu} $

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stopping-times

> Let $\tau $,$ \nu$ be stopping times. Show $F_{\tau \land \nu}=F_{\tau} \cap F_{\nu}$.

Definitons I am using are given by:
$$F_\nu := \{A \in F_{\infty} \mid A \cap \{\nu =n \} \in F_n \forall n\} $$
and
Let $\{F_n\}$ be a filtration on $(\Omega,F)$, then $\tau : \Omega \to \mathbb N \cup \{\infty\}$ is called an $F$ stopping time if for all $n \in \mathbb N_0$ we have $\{\tau=n \} \in F_n.$

My attempt:
\begin{align}
F_{\tau \land \nu}&=\{A \in F_{\infty} \mid A \cap \{\tau \land\nu =n \} \in F_n \forall n\}\\
&=\{A \in F_{\infty} \mid A \cap (\{\tau =n \}\cup\{\nu=n\}) \in F_n \forall n\}\\
&=\{A \in F_{\infty} \mid A \cap \{\tau =n \} \in F_n \forall n\} \cup \{A \in F_{\infty} \mid A \cap \{\nu =n \} \in F_n \forall n\}\\
&= F_{\nu }\cup F_{\tau}.
\end{align}

I know that $ \{\tau \land\nu =n \}= \{\tau=n \}\cup \{\nu=n \}$, but obviously  I am doing something wrong. Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: The wrong step (frankly rather bizarre) is to state that $$\{A \in F_{\infty} \mid A \cap (\{\tau =n \}\cup\{\nu=n\}) \in F_n \forall n\}$$ is also $$\{A \in F_{\infty} \mid A \cap \{\tau =n \} \in F_n \forall n\} \cup \{A \in F_{\infty} \mid A \cap \{\nu =n \} \in F_n \forall n\}$$ Before that, you seem to assert that $$\{\tau \land\nu =n \} =\{\tau =n \}\cup\{\nu=n\}$$ which is wrong as well.

Comment: @Did I was thinking of {τ∧ν <=n}={τ<=n}∪{ν<=n}, but my statement is not true. But how should one get started then? I am clueless..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Very often if one should show that two sets are equal it's easier to do it in two steps: 
First show "$\subseteq$" and then "$\supseteq$".

For "$\subseteq$" we take an $A \in F_{\tau \wedge \nu}$ so it's given that $$A \cap \{\tau \wedge \nu = n\} \in F_n$$ for all $n\in \Bbb N$ and we have to show that $A \in F_\tau$ as well as $A \in F_\nu$.

We know that $\tau$ is a stopping time hence $\{\tau = n\},\{\tau \le n\}, \{\tau > n\}$ and $\{\tau \ge n\}$ are in $F_n$

$F_n$ is a $\sigma$-algebra so also the intersection of sets of it are contained in $F_n$, now intersect $\{\tau > n\}$ with $A \cap \{\tau \wedge \nu = n\}$ and simplify (remember: $\tau \wedge \nu$ is the minimum of $\tau$ and $\nu$).

For "$\supseteq$" we assume $$A \cap \{\tau = n\} \in F_n$$
as well as $$A \cap \{\nu = n\} \in F_n$$

Again we know $\{\nu \ge n\}$ and $\{\tau \ge n\}$ are in $F_n$ so intersect the first set with the first expression and the second set with the second expression and unify the resulting sets.

Comment: First: Use the $\LaTeX$ formulas otherwise your comments are not readable. 
Then: $\{\tau > n\}$ is not a stopping time but a measurable set BECAUSE $\tau$ is a stopping time. You should look-up definitions again to get along with them. 
Your equation is nonsense! $\{\tau > n\}$ is measurable because it's the complement of $$\{\tau \le n\} = \bigcup_{k \le n} \{\tau = k\}$$
And last but not least: Why should the assumption $\nu \le \tau$ be "without any restriction"? Indeed this is a very hard restriction because in general neither $\tau \le \nu$ nor $\nu \le \tau$ has to hold.

Comment: I tried to understand your idea, but I do not get why one has to intersect with your stated set in the first inclusion

Comment: On the one hand we have by assumption $$A \cap \{\tau \wedge \nu = n\} \in F_n$$ but then also $$A \cap \{\tau \wedge \nu = n\} \cap \{\tau > n\} \in F_n$$Consider that $$ \{\tau \wedge \nu = n\} \cap \{\tau > n\} = \{\nu = n\} \cap \{\tau > n\}$$ so we have $$A \cap  \{\nu = n\} \cap \{\tau > n\} \in F_n$$
On the other hand we have by assumption  $A \in F_{\tau \wedge \nu}$  $$A \cap \{\tau \wedge \nu \le n\} \in F_n$$ but then also $$A \cap \{\tau \wedge \nu \le n\} \cap \{\nu = n\} = A \cap \{\tau \le n\} \cap \{\nu = n\}\in F_n$$Unify both set gets $$A \cap \{\nu = n\}  \in F_n$$

Comment: thank you for your patience and explanations. I really appreciate it